# How to manage (or eliminate) parallel class hierarchies?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm designing a simple form creation engine, in which users may compose new forms using various boilerplate field types (Date, Text, DropDown)

I decided to model the domain object (Form Field) independently of the objects that would be used to render these fields to a UI.

Here's the interface that defines the contract for the domain and some of it's specializations:

```
namespace Acme.Core.Domain{
    public interface IFormField
            {
                bool Visible { get; set; }
                string Key { get; set; }
                event EventHandler<FieldVisibilityChangedEventArgs> VisibilityChanged;
                FieldType Type{get;}
                void Validate(IEnumerable<ValidationError> errors);
                int DataId {get;set;}
            }

    public interface IDropDownField:IFormField{

                IDictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }
                KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedValue { get; set; }

        }
     public interface IDateField:IFormField{

                DateTime? SelectedDate{get;set}

        }
}
```

For the UI side of things, I constructed a parallel type hierarchy.  This keeps the domain object, which is concerned with business rules around data validation separate from UI concerns, namely how to render a given field (MVC HtmlHelper vs WebForm WebControl):

```
namespace Acme.UI{

        public interface IControl 
        {
                //parallel to IFormField
                bool Visible { get; set; }
                string ID { get; set; }     
        }

        public interface IDropListControl:IControl 
        {
                //parallel to IDropDownField

        }
        public interface IDatePickerControl: IControl 
        {
                //parallel to IDateField

        }

       public interface IControlFactory {

             IControl CreateControl(IFormField field);
       }
    }
```

While this design gives me the freedom to design the domain model independently of the UI, I haven't come across a clean way to connect and manage the two hierarchies. I feel like I should be able to leverage generics to connect parallel classes to one another, but I can't quite grok how that would look.  Is there a pattern that solves the association problem or eliminates the need for a parallel class hierarchies altogether?

EDIT:  My UI tier references the my business layer (Core.csproj).  Here are a few examples of how I connect the UI class hierarchy to the domain class hierarchy. These types don't currently use generics, but I feel that they ought to.

```
    // create concrete instances of IControl based on the the domain object passed in 
   public interface IControlFactory {

                 IControl CreateControl(IFormField field);
       }
       // scrape values form the UI controls and apply them to the appropriate domain object
       public interface IFormFieldDataBinder{

                void Bind(IFormField field, IControl control);
       }
```

Comment: How do you put the two together in a final application? Will the UI interfaces refer to the domain interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference between the two hierarchies are so small you really should consider what the value -or- distinction is. If all you are considering is having, for instance, multiple dropdownlist controls that have a different rendering forms then ask yourself, if not in the designer, where are you going to pick concrete controls?

Perhaps your `IDropdownListControl` can be a base class with an abstract 'Render' method?

Your `IFormField` and `IControl` are so similar, I don't see what you buy with having both?

The `IDropDownField` in particular really looks like a model object in MVC terms, it's about data the field would hold when a form is instantiated. It's not about how a form is shaped (you stated it was a domain model).

Should all `IDropListControls` support the model `IDropDownField` perhaps? (in which case I would really just drop the `IDropDownField` and declare the properties directly on `IDropListControl`).

Consider the Reused Abstraction Principle. For every interface you create, can you think of two implementations or are they really just concrete classes?

Comment: The two class hierarchies are more different than I represented them to be and I edited my question to reflect this.  For example, I use my domain objects to perform data validation, to determine whether they should be visible/hidden, and to handle other business rule centric operations. The UI class hierarchy is only concerned with how to represent one of the domain objects (i.e. fields) in a specific UI tech. Currently, the UI tech is Asp.Net WebControls, but I could easily swap it out to be MVC HtmlHelpers in the future.  For this reason, I don't think I can merge the two families together.